# mysql compare two tables to find not matched records

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

See these two sample tables:

Table 1:

id   FN  LN  Email

1        A                  B                     C

2        D                  E                     F

3        G                  H                     I

Table 2:

id   FN  LN  Email

1        A            Z                     C

2        D           E                     F

3        G           H                     I

i want the output which are not equal from table1 and show only change one. I have tried many ways but no results.

output:

id    LN

---- ---

1         Z

Comment: if 3 G changed to 3 K how would your expected output look? (including the change to 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1(id int,  FN varchar(1), LN varchar(1), Email varchar(1));
insert into t1 values
(1 ,  'A',   'B',     'C'),
(2 ,  'D' ,  'E',     'F'),
(3 ,  'G' ,  'H',     'I');

drop table if exists t2;
create table t2(id int,  FN varchar(1), LN varchar(1), Email varchar(1));
insert into t2 values
(1 ,  'A',   'Z',     'C'),
(2 ,  'D' ,  'E',     'F'),
(3 ,  'k' ,  'H',     'l');

select t1.id,
        case when t1.fn <> t2.fn then 'FN'
        when t1.ln <> t2.ln then 'LN'
        when t1.email <> t2.email then 'email'
        END AS FieldChanged,
        case when t1.fn <> t2.fn then t2.fn
        when t1.ln <> t2.ln then t2.ln
        when t1.email <> t2.email then t2.email
        END AS FieldChangedTo

from t1
join t2 on t1.id = t2.id

where t1.fn <> t2.fn or
        t1.ln <> t2.ln or
        t1.email <> t2.email
```

Result

```
+------+--------------+----------------+
| id   | FieldChanged | FieldChangedTo |
+------+--------------+----------------+
|    1 | LN           | Z              |
|    3 | FN           | k              |
+------+--------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that id is the same and any other column differs, you should do it so:

```
select * from table1
join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where table1.firstname != table2.firstname or
      table1.middlename != table2.middlename or 
      table1.lastname != table2.lastname
```

Comment: i have tied ur method getting not exact results,But the P.salmon work fine as i wanted it.Anyway thanks @quantummind :)